# Rearwheel drive car going up the slope with uniform velocity. Will there be friction on front wheel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

This is the full question-

**An automobile with the distance between front and rear wheels 3.0 m and height of centre of gravity 300 mm is traveling over a roadway inclined at an angle θ with horizontal. The coefficient of static and dynamic friction are 0.6 and 0.5 respectively. The automobile is a rear wheel drive and has a load of 18 kN. What is the maximum inclination θmax that the automobile can climb at uniform speed?**

I have the solution, but the solution takes friction on front wheel as zero.

As per my understanding, there should be friction down the slope to provide the rotation. If this is correct, then how to solve the above question?

Comment: I think the assumption of your solution is OK.  The car moving at constant speed; so the front wheels are rotating at constant speed; so you can ignore the front wheels  (unless you want to account for the friction of the front wheel bearings, but I don't think you do).

Comment: If there is no friction on front wheel, how is it rotating? Shouldn't it be sliding. I know friction is zero on plane surface in case of uniform circular motion. But when it is going up, there is gravity pulling it down, so there should be a torque to make it move with constant speed.

Comment: Are you in steady state, where you are already at speed X? If so then the tire is already rotating.  However, if you are starting from speed 0, then you do need to account for the acceleration of the car, and the angular acceleration of all four wheels, etc.  (your problem sounds like steady state).

Comment: OK, so next time I encounter such problem, I should just take friction as zero in case of uniform rolling motion (irrespective of slope), unless friction is necessary to make net torque zero (as in case of rear wheel in this question).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike kinetic friction where the value is known from the normal force and the coefficient of friction, static friction can rise (to a limit) or fall depending on the other forces involved.

As a rear-wheel drive car, we assume that the only torque that the car can supply to the front wheels is through the brake.  So if the brakes aren't applied, the torque on the wheel from the axle is zero.

Then the force of friction from the road is the only torque on the wheel.

$$ \tau = FR = \alpha I$$

If the car is not accelerating, the wheel has zero angular acceleration and force on the wheel from friction can be considered to be zero.

(In a real car, there will be some small rotational drag that will have to be offset by friction from the road.  But for a problem like this, that drag can be ignored)

Comment: This is what I don't understand- for friction to be zero, net torque (other than friction) should be zero. But gravity is slowing the car, isn't it? So, shouldn't there be friction to cancel out the effect of gravity.

Comment: No.  That force is done by the rear wheels, not the front wheels.  The front wheels are just spinning

Comment: @Jake The problem says it's moving at a uniform speed. Draw a FBD for a front wheel. Look at which force (not *forces*) has a torque about the center of the wheel, and then conclude that this force must be $0$ for the car to be moving at a constant speed.

Answer (score 0):

There is friction between the front wheels and the road but it is irrelevant. You need to remember that the friction between the front wheels and the road is not transferred to the car in this case because the wheels are connected to the car by bearings which are practically frictionless. The friction between the front wheels and the road only serves the purpose of keeping the car from sliding off its intended path- it has nothing to do with propelling the car.